# How to start the object

Tags: scala, parameter-passing

i need help with this code.

```
object test {
  var list : Vector[MyType] = null
}

object foo extends MyType { // Mytype is a trait
    println("TEST ")
    test.list.:+(foo)
    def myfunc() { //need to define this as this is there in the trait
       // i do some operations
     } 
  }


object Bar extends MyType { // Mytype is a trait
    println("TEST ")
    test.list.:+(Bar)
    def myfunc(){
      // i do some operations
    } 
  }
```

now i want to go through the list and call myfunc() for all the objects that are extending MyType.

```
test.list foreach( t2 => t2.myfunc() )
```

the value's are not getting added to the list. Can someone let me know what i am doing wrong. Its not working.  Is there a way to get that print statement working?

Comment: You need to reformat your example code.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that the object is not constructed as a class, so that the code is called automatically. You could do two things. Either you extend `App` and call `main` or you write a function.

```
trait X

object test {
  var list = Vector.empty[X]
}

object Foo extends App with X {
  test.list :+= Foo
  override def toString() = "Foo"
}

object Bar extends X {
  def add() {
    test.list :+= Bar
  }
  override def toString() = "Bar"
}

Foo.main(null)
Bar.add()
test.list foreach println
```

This code prints:

```
Foo
Bar
```

Extending App only adds a main methode to an object, containing all the code in the object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize test with an empty Vector rather than `null`.  The way to do that in Scala is to use the factory method from the `Vector` object, and let type-inference do its job.  For example:

```
var list = Vector.empty[MyType]
```

As you get the practice of doing that, you'll find yourself more focused on *creating the data* than on declaring its type, which in this case would have resolve this error before it happened.

Next the operation

```
test.list.:+(foo)
```

will not update `test.list` because, since `Vector` is immmutable, this method just returns a new updated copy and cannot affect the reference of `list`.

Try instead

```
test.list = test.list.:+(foo)
// or (with more idiomatic operator notation)
test.list = test.list :+ foo
// or (using syntactic sugar)
test.list :+= foo
```

Comment: Is there any way i can print that "TEST" ??? under what senario will it get printed ???

Comment: With your update, TEST should be printed as your class hierarchy is resolved and initialized by the ClassLoader.  In short, long before your `foreach` loop runs.